# Rectifier design priority?voltage or current?

Tags: rectifier

I'm curious..which one is better..have a high voltage or high in current?
If i want to design a rectifier cct, which one is the main priority? Large load,higher voltage but less current will be generated...
if i'm using small load, more current and less voltage generated...

Comment: If you are fat you buy big clothes; If you are thin you buy smaller clothes.

Comment: Can you state your requirements?

Comment: generally, very small input (+- -40dBm) and the output will be used to power up some mobile devices...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the load you are driving.

e.g I need to drive a few relays, I will check their volts requirement (e.g 12V DC) - my rectifier cct will have to be a low volts one. Then I will check the current req to power them up and that will give me the max current limit for my rectifier cct.

There is no standard / general general purpose rectifier ckt - all are designed with a specific o/p in mind.

For electronics you could consider a simple circuit which can provide 48, 24, 12 and +/- 5 V o/p. Using a step down trfm (220/60V AC) and then linear regulators / switching regulators. Keep in mind that this general purpose psu will be of low power.

You could also consider having a variable regulator instead.

Answer (score 0):

remember, rectifier efficiency for silicon diode with bridge conf. is: load in watts/(load in watts+2*0.7*I load). Now decide what efficiency you would like to work with.vtingole